# Why does ASP.NET MVC path appear with variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my MVC app, why does

```
Return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Forms", New With {.member = "123"})
```

return

```
http://localhost:13/Forms/Edit?member=123
```

insted of

```
http://localhost:13/Forms/Edit/123
```

?

And why does

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "Edit", "Forms", New With {.member = "123"}, Nothing)%>
```

do the same thing?

Comment: Post the MVC route table and you'll get better answers...

Comment: The combo of your mention of the route table and @tvanoffson's answer led me to the solution - the default MapRoute was listed first, so it was trumping anything I added after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard routing is set up to use id as the third parameter.  Change "member" to "id" and you will get the route that you expect.

```
Return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Forms", New With { .id = "123"})
```

Answer (score 6):

As tvanfosson says, "id" is what the default route engine is set to look for.  Anything else as the 3rd param and it will be tacted on as a querystring.

Why? Because of this method in your Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

You can change this by adding an additional routes.MapRoute() line, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2",
    "{controller}/{action}/{member}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", member = "" }
);
```